# Orthogonal Projection of Point onto Line

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra

I'm referencing a mathematics paper, but the terminology is strange, and I'm unsure of how to code the following:

Return if the orthogonal projection of Point P exists on S(P2, P3).

I found `std::inner_product` but not sure if thats the correct method to use.

Comment: What's the full question? Inner_product is another name for dot product but whether you need to use it here depends on the question.

Comment: @sashang thanks ! I thought they were slightly different, I wanted to know how to use this given a struct with points x and y and not a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the orthogonal projection of P (on the line given by P2 and P3) to be inside the segment [P2,P3]. Mathematically, it writes simply (I'm noting vect(A, B) the vector AB, because I do not know how to use the arrow notation):

```
0 <= vect(P2, P) . vect (P2, P3) <= vect(P2, P3) . vect(P2, P3)
```

You can indeed use `std::inner_product` but if your points are something as simple as:

```
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

You could just use

```
double operator - (const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x - b.x + a.y - b.y;
}
double operator * (const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}
```

And the mathematical formula just gives:

```
bool is_proj_inside(const Point& P, const Point& P2, const Point& P3) {
    double p_proj = (P - P2) * (P3 - P2);
    double p3_proj = (P3 - P2) * (P3 - P2);

    return (p_proj >= 0) && (p_proj <= p3_proj);
}
```

Comment: Is the second check `(p_proj <= p3_proj)` just checking if the point P` is to the left of P3?

Comment: @DaynaJuliana: that's the reason why I started with a mathematical point of view. p_proj >= 0 means it is after P2 (in the line oriented P2->P3) and p_proj <= p3_proj means it is before P3. BTW p3_proj >=0 is guaranteed because it as a squared product.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is that you project P onto S and then check whether that projection P' is between P2 and P3.

To make it a little easier you say that P2 is the support-vector of S and P3-P2 is the direction-vector. You then project P-P2 onto the normalized P3-P2 (you compute the scalar-product between them) which gives you the distance D of P' to P2. 
Now in your case you only want to know if P' is between P2 and P3. That is true if D is between 0 and 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! First, would I not normalize P-P2 ?

Comment: Good question. No you wouldn't because then the distance of P to P2 would have no influence on P' but it should.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use inner_product (dot product) to take the result in very simple way.

Make vectors

```
V2 = P - P2
V3 = P - P3
V =  P3 - P2
```

Find signs of dot products
`D2 = Dot(V2,V)` and `D3 = Dot(V3,V)`

Projection of Point P lies at S(P2, P3), if

```
D2 >=0 and
D3 <=0
```

Note - there is no need in normalizations, square roots etc. Just some subtractions, multiplications and additions.

(Explanation - angles `P-P2-P3` and `P-P3-P2` should be acute or right)

Comment: Seems like the two answers are at odds. How does this differ than the other answer? Also doesn't V need to be normalized?

Comment: We compare only signs, so normalization is not needed. Two answers are not at odds - they just present different approaches (there are many ways to solve this problem)